# Carrierwave + Mongoid full url in json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid, carrierwave

I am trying to build an api for a mobile app and am using Carrierwave and Mongoid. Everything works fine with uploading and retrieving the images, but when i generate the json response the image urls simply show a path/to/image.png instead of http://localhost:3000/path/to/image.png.

How do I get my app to generate the full url to the image. I have done an extensive search on google but am unable to find any solid solutions.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can do this with carrierwave by default, but you can workaround this by this monkey patch

```
module CarrierWave::Uploader::Url
  def url
    if $request
      if file.respond_to?(:url) and not file.url.blank?
        $request.protocol + $request.host_with_port + file.url
      elsif current_path
        $request.protocol + $request.host_with_port + (base_path || "") + File.expand_path(current_path).gsub(File.expand_path(root), '')
      end
    else
      raise ArgumentError, "Request object is empty"
    end

  end

end
```

since you cannot access the rails `session/request` info from the uploader(any model), you need to define the `before_filter` in `application_controller` to load the request data

```
  before_filter :load_request

  def load_request
    $request = request
  end
```

I have tested this patch only in local storage/mongoid. I dont know how this will work in amazon s3/fog..

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is the monkey patch supposed to go into the uploader file? I am also using local storage for the images (Grid FS).

Comment: you can put it in the carrierwave initializer, that will do the trick.. i believe it will be fine for local storage too, but you can verify.. :)